# woocommerce product image not showing on loop

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have problem with product image for woocommerce specific categories.Here Single product page image showing but not showing image on shop loop.
reference url where product image not showing https://blissbeautyandglitter.com/product-category/hair/hair-lace-front-wigs/

But other product catagories where image showing 
https://blissbeautyandglitter.com/product-category/hair-care/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just **replace** this code in your **css** file:

`/wp-content/themes/organ/skins/default/style.css`

In line number: **3334**

```
.products-grid .item .item-inner .item-img img {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
    transition-duration: 500ms;
    -webkit-transition-property: transform;
    transition-property: transform;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    max-width: inherit !important;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply I change css code but unfortunately not working

Comment: I have check your css file not updated..check right file your to update..

Comment: great.Thank you so much my Friend... :)

Answer (score 0):

The images are showing, they are just 1px by 1px.  To fix this, just set their height and width properties.

```
$('.product-image>img').css({height:'100%',width:'100%'})
```